# Array allocation problem

Tags: c++

This is probably a very easy question, but for some reason I don'd understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Anyways, I got a function that takes in `function(size_type m, size_type n)` and I have to build an array which is pointed to by a private variable in the class called `int *value`. I am trying to create an integer array of `mxn` size but I am having difficulty changing the type of m and n.

I tried:

`*value = int[(int)m*(int)n];`

as well as using `(unsigned int)` can someone please help.

EDIT: size_type isn't declared as any type in the specs

Comment: provide more source code....tsss...what is size_type???????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may consider:

```
value = new int[m*n];
```

because you need to create a *dynamic* array.  You will need to remember to `delete []` this at the correct times.

You will probably find it easier to work with a `std::vector`, because the memory management is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
typedef int size_type; //could also be this or that other type...

void myFunction(size_type m, size_type n)
{
   int array[(int) m * (int) n ];
   int *value = array;
};

int main()
{
   myFunction(2, 2);
   return 0;
}
```

Or do you need `value` outside of the function? Do you want the function to return the `value`?